# mvn eclipse:eclipse within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have the m2Eclipse plugin from Sonatype installed in my IDE. It allows me to run various maven commands (package, install, etc.) by right-clicking on a `pom.xml` file and navigating to the "Run As" menu.

However, I haven't figuered out how to the equivalent of `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from within the IDE, is this possible?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, when you **right-click** over the project, in the **Maven** sub-menu, you have an **Update Project Configuration** command which does precisely that.

[alt text http://scott.phillips.name/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Maven-Context_Menu.png](http://scott.phillips.name/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Maven-Context_Menu.png)

Comment: Eh....not I don't. Maybe you and I have different versions of the plugin installed?

Comment: That menu entry was available for ages. But it's only in the Maven menu of the project itself, not the pom.xml or anywhere else.